# How to map Enter, Ctrl-Enter and Shift-Enter in Neovim (nvim-cmp)?

Tags: neovim, key-bindings, plugin-nvim-cmp, kitty-terminal, nvim-cmp

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42461580)

**My Kitty conf**

```
map shift+enter send_text all \x1b[13;2u
map ctrl+enter send_text all \x1b[13;5u
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359878/how-to-map-shift-enter#comment124634141_42461580)

**My Tmux conf**

```
bind -n S-Enter send-keys Escape "[13;2u"
bind -n C-Enter send-keys Escape "[13;5u"
```

And according to [the recommended configuration example](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp/blob/538e37ba87284942c1d76ed38dd497e54e65b891/README.md?plain=1#L82)

**My nvim-cmp conf**

```lua
local M = {}
M.cmp_mappings = {
  ["<CR>"] = require("cmp").mapping.confirm({ select = false }),
  ["<C-j>"] = require("cmp").mapping.select_next_item(),
  ["<C-k>"] = require("cmp").mapping.select_prev_item(),
  ["<C-s>"] = require("cmp").mapping.abort(),

  ["<S-CR>"] = require("cmp").mapping.confirm({ select = true }),
  ["<C-CR>"] = require("cmp").mapping.confirm({ select = false }),
}
return M
```

#### Description

Everything seems alright according to the references I shared above. My mappings for `selecting next/prev item` and `aborting` does work. This indicates that I'm at the **right point** and **my nvim-cmp configuration file does work along with all the other configurations**!

However, my mappings `Enter`, `Control+Enter` and `Shift+Enter` does not work. The problem seems to occur in only those three keys/mappings.

I can confirm that:

- When I do `Ctrl+V Enter` in insert mode, it writes `<CR>`
- When I do `Ctrl+V Shit+Enter` in insert mode, it writes `<S-CR>`
- When I do `Ctrl+V Ctrl+Enter` in insert mode, it writes `<C-CR>`

According to these outputs, everything seems normal and it seems like it should work, but it doesn't.

I guess `Enter` is the default key for selecting the autosuggestion, and I want to make it not select autosuggestions. I only want to use `Shift+Enter` to select autosuggestions.

One thing I noticed is, as long as I include the mappings for `<S-CR>` and `<C-CR>`, when I pressed `Shift+Enter` or `Ctrl+Enter` they both select the autosuggestion no matter how I configured their `select` parameter (even if I set it `false`). However if they're not included in the code, meaning when I remove/uncomment the lines associated with mapping `<S-CR>` and `<C-CR>`, they don't select the autosuggestion. Which once again proves that my terminal and Neovim evaluate `Enter`, `Shift+Enter` and `Ctrl+Enter` individually, separately.

I appreciate any help!

## UPDATE

Comment: Could you tell us what is the result of `:set <S-CR>?` and `:set <C-CR>?`? What is the result of typing in insert mode Ctrl-v Shift-Enter? What is the result of typing in insert mode Ctrl-v Ctrl-Enter?

Comment: `:set <S-CR>` outputs `Unknown option: <S-CR>` ||||||||||| `:set <C-CR>` outputs `Unknown option: <C-CR>`  |||||||||||  `:set <CR>` outputs `Key code not set: <CR>`  |||||||||||  Other than that, I already mentioned what Ctrl-V Shift-Enter and Ctrl-Enter resulted in insert mode in my original question.

Comment: if you issue the following commands `:nmap <C-CR> <cmd>echom 'Ctrl-Enter'<CR>` and `:nmap <S-CR> <cmd>echom 'Shift-Enter'<CR>` what is the message displayed when you type `<S-CR>` and `<C-CR>` respectively?

Comment: The messages are `Ctrl-Enter` and `Shift-Enter` respectively.

Comment: Other than that, I can map both `<S-CR>` and `<C-CR>` to do something in insert mode. So I guess the problem is with `nvim-cmp`.

Comment: Looks indeed that the problem is in `nvim-cmp`. What if you keep only the line `["<S-CR>"] = require("cmp").mapping.confirm({ select = true }),` or only the line `["<S-CR>"] = require("cmp").mapping.confirm({ select = false }),` do you have a different behavior? In other words is the problem of `nvim-cmp` configuration?

Comment: No different behaviors, everything works as I explained in the question description. (i.e Shift-Enter still selects when the configuration lines with the `<C-CR>` and `<CR>` are removed and `<S-CR>`'s `select` flag is set to `false` or `true` )

Comment: But then is the `select` parameter the correct one? If there is no difference in behavior I suppose the problem is the `call` and not the mapping.

Comment: It seems so [here](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp/blob/538e37ba87284942c1d76ed38dd497e54e65b891/README.md?plain=1#L82)

Comment: The parameter exist but the behavior could be influenced by other parameters or by other options I see`cmp.confirm({ behavior = cmp.ConfirmBehavior.Insert, select = true })`.

Comment: It doesnt seem to have an effect, [here](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp/issues/1623#issuecomment-1596114131)